# How can change script.js file into bundel.js file using browserify?

Tags: node.js, browserify

I want to change my `script.js` file into `bundel.js` file using `browserify`:

```
browserify script.js > bundel.js
```

Here I got an error:

> Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\ASUS\nodescript.js' from 'C:\Users\ASUS_fake.js'
> required by C:\Users\ASUS_fake.js

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problem in the last 1 hour and came here but finding no answer went back to the basics and resolved the issue through:

1. Uninstalling browserify globally to avoid aliases

   `npm uninstall browserify -g`
2. Went to the project folder and installed browserify

   `npm install browserify -g`

This did the trick and I was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to look for is if the npm package you are trying to require is valid.

One time I incorrectly install moment by using `npm i momentjs` (this library doesn't exist) instead of `npm i moment` (the correct library). As a result , I got the same exact error.

Realizing my dumb mistake, I install the correct momentjs library and required it. After that it worked.